# ob_end_flush() - не работает. Не могу выяснить причину

Tags: php

Добрый день дорогие друзья. На днях появилась проблема с `ob_end_flush()` , она перестала работать. Причину не могу выяснить.
Код таков.

```
if(ob_end_flush()){
    ob_start();
       curl запрос на сайт и прочие фильтры 
    $data = ob_get_content();
} flush();
```

Поставил `else` тоже не дало результата при случае false. 
а когда убираю `if(ob_end_flush()){ } flush();` то все работает. 
Единственное но, это то, что результат выводит но не так как надо ;

Comment: а в чем смысл if(ob_end_flush()){ ?

Comment: Эта функция отправит содержимое буфера вывода (если оно имеется) и отключит эту буферизацию вывода.

Comment: сайт на codeinterger.. без ob_end_flush header попадает в конец сайта ниже foother, с ob_end_flush она стоит на верху .. Почему это так я не могу понять .. Но знаю одно что ob_end_flush это исправляет это .. Все было ок до сегодня .. А сегодня этот ob_end_flush умер , причину не могу найти даже удалил все содиржимое в ob_start(); и поставил простой echo , но не сработало ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написано в комментах - сайт на фреймворке codeinterger . А фреймфорки зачастую используют вложенную схему ob. Читай http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php

> Буферы вывода помещаются в стек, то есть допускается вызов ob_start()
>   после вызова другой активной ob_start(). При этом необходимо вызывать
>   ob_end_flush() соответствующее количество раз.

Попробй несколько раз вызвать `ob_end_flush()` - раз 5 для верности :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо , сработало !!!!!!!!!!